# Clean and simple derivation of Johnson Nyquist noise

Tags: thermodynamics, electricity, thermal-radiation, noise

I am not sure to get the derivation of Johnson Nyquist noise. I would like to understand it under black-body radiation approach.

Consider this reference: http://www.pas.rochester.edu/~dmw/ast203/Lectures/Lect_20.pdf

Considering the Johnson Nyquist noise as a 1d blackbody version, what I expect is to say that we study a radiation that has thermalized with the electrical circuit at temperature T.

Then I need to compute the energy density per unit length (because 1D) and unit frequency.

In the 3D blackbody we consider stationnary waves. Here it seems it is the same. But why ?

Does that mean the wire must be connected to ground in x=0 and x=L ? If not, why can we impose stationnary waves in the derivation ?

Finally I dont get the point of putting two resistors. For me what matters is only to consider waves here. The fact we will be able to talk about power flow is just because of propagation, it is not related to the presence or not of a resistor.

I am very confused

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to "ground" a transmission line anywhere for Nyquist's derivation to work, you need to ground a transmission line at its ends if you do not want to get electrocuted while touching it.

The role of the transmission line in this derivation is to allow for two resistors, one at each end, that are potentially at different temperatures to equilibrate thermally.  Having a simple transmission line connecting them constrains the possible *electromagnetic modes* by which the resistors exchange energy here forming a simple discrete sequence numbered by the possible standing waves given the length of the line. In thermal equilibrium one resistor emits as much wave energy, that is propagating waves, as it absorbs from the other end. If they are at different temperature then the one at higher temperature will emit, on the average, higher amplitude waves than it absorbs while the other will absorb more than it emits until they reach the same temperature at which point the resistors will be in a dynamic equilibrium with each other and with the propagating medium, here the transmission line.

If you connected the terminals of the resistors directly to one another (zero length transmission line) then they could never equilibrate within the confines of the laws of Kirchhoff (KVL, KIL), Ohm ($V=RI$) and Joule ($I^2R$) (ie. purely by electrical phenomena) for then their voltages would not be fluctuating independently one from another.

---

From the Master himself, see [1]:

> At any instant after equilibrium has been established, let the line be
>   isolated from the conductors, say, by the application of short circuits at the
>   two ends. Under these conditions there is complete reflection at the two
>   ends and the energy which was on the line at the time of isolation remains
>   trapped. Now, instead of describing the waves on the line as two trains
>   traveling in opposite directions, it is permissible to describe the line as
>   vibrating at its natural frequencies. Corresponding to the lowest frequency the voltage wave has a node at each end and no intermediate nodes. The
>   frequency corresponding to this mode of vibration is $\nu/2l$. The next higher
>   natural frequency is $2\nu/2l$. For this mode of vibration there is a node at each
>   end and one in the middle. Similarly there are natural frequencies $3\nu/2l,
> 4\nu/2l$, etc. Consider a frequency range extending from $\nu$ cycles per second
>   to $\nu+d\nu$ cycles per second, i.e., a frequency range of width $d\nu$. The number of modes of vibration, or degrees of freedom, lying within this range may be taken to be $2ld\nu/\nu$, provided $l$ is taken sufficiently large to make this expression a great number. Under this condition it is permissible to speak of the average energy per degree of freedom as a definite quantity. To each
>   degree of freedom there corresponds an energy equal to $kT$ on the average,
>   on the basis of the equipartition law, where $k$ is the Boltzmann constant.
>   Of this energy, one-half is magnetic and one-half is electric. The total energy
>   of the vibrations within the frequency interval $d\nu$ is then seen to be $2lkTd\nu/\nu$. But since there is no reflection this is the energy within that frequency interval which was transferred from the two conductors to the line during the time of transit $l/\nu$. The average power, transferred from each conductor to the line within the frequency interval $d\nu$ during the time interval $l/\nu$ is therefore $kTd\nu$."

[1] Nyquist: "THERMAL AGITATION OF ELECTRIC CHARGE IN CONDUCTORS" Phys. Rev. JULY, 1928, pp110-113

Comment: Well I don't understand the role of the resistor in the derivation then. You can get the power radiated per unit frequency and unit length without having talked at all about any resistor. This is why for me I could only consider a line without resistor at all to get to this power, this confuses me. About the standing waves, why are those the mode we must consider ? To have them we must have $0$ potential in $x=0$ and $x=L$ why is it true here ?

Comment: The *purpose* of the derivation is to find the rms voltage fluctuation per unit bandwidth across the terminals of a resistor in equilibrium, ie. to prove that $\langle v^2 \rangle = 4k_BTR$ per unit bandwidth. The noisy resistor is the *source* of the waves that are on the line.

Comment: Well I'm sorry but many things confuses me still. Allright we need the resistor because we want to have RMS voltage around it. But. First: why do we consider stationnary waves ? To consider them we must impose boundary conditions and **motivate** them. Here I don't see any motivation to consider those modes. Then, the law $P=V^2/R$ around a resistor is true when there are no propagation phenomenon. Here we take the power associated to the right moving waves to infer the voltage around the transistor. This is also very confusing.

Comment: see my edit above

Comment: I read the paper. Very instructive. So the fact we can deal with stationnary waves is a trick in the reasonning. Basically he considers the situation at thermal equilibrium with the two resistors. Then he needs to know the energy in the line. To access to it his "trick" is to "fastly" remove the resistor and connect to the ground the $x=0$ and $x=L$ lines. Doing so we didn't dissipate any energy in principle. Thus we can reason on this new situation to find the energy in the line. Would you agree with this point ?

Comment: yes, this is my view, too